# How to count instance variable, Methods, Classes and comment lines in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to count instance variable, Methods, Classes and comment lines in Ruby.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
  ssl_required :edit_account
    def index
      @admin_projects = @admin.projects.find(:all, :conditions => ["project_completed=?",0])
      total_tasks = find_project_and_completed_task_before_and_after_date(@admin_projects)
      @project_task_bar_chart = GoogleChart::BarChart.new('450x150', "", :horizontal, true)
      @project_task_bar_chart.data_encoding = :text
      max_cate_task = total_tasks[2].sort.last
      @project_task_bar_chart.data "Complete Before Due Date", total_tasks[1], '67ce04' 
      @project_task_bar_chart.data "Complete After Due Date", total_tasks[0], 'ff0000' 
    end

#if request.xhr?
#@project = @admin.projects.find(:first,:conditions => ["projects.id = ?",params[:project_id].to_i])
```

Comment: You can use a [ruby parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser).

Comment: I didn't get any thing because i am learner i couldn't understand your github project

Comment: Yeah well, you got to do  some learning first. Walking AST is moderately difficult task, compared to "hello world" programs.

Answer (score 3):

The question, "how many?", is answered by the sizes of the arrays referred to below, except for the number of classes.

**Instance variables**

`C.new.instance_variables` returns an array of an instance of class `C`'s instance variables.

`C.instance_variables` returns an array of class `C`'s instance variables (generally referred to as *class instance variables*).

For example:

```
class A
  @a = 'cat'
  def initialize
    @b = 'dog'
    @c = 'pig'
  end
end

A.instance_variables     #=> [:@a] 
A.new.instance_variables #=> [:@b, :@c]
```

**Instance methods**

`C.instance_methods` (or `C.new.methods`) returns an array of `C`'s instance methods, including inherited ones. `C` can also be a module that is not a class.

`C.instance_methods(false)` (or `C.new.methods(false)`) returns an array of `C`'s instance methods defined on class `C`. `C` can also be a module that is not a class. Modules do not inherit methods, so if `C` is a module, `C.instance_methods == C.instance_methods(false)`.

The ownership of one of class `C`'s instance methods `m` can be obtains with `C.instance_method(:m).owner`.

**Class Methods**

`C.methods` and `C.methods(false)` return class `C`'s class methods. That is also the case when `C` is a module that is not a class.

The ownership of one of class `C`'s class methods `m` can be obtained with `C.method(:m).owner`.

**Classes**

Execute

```
GC.start
```

to force immediate garbage collection, then:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a.size
```

or

```
ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]
```

if singleton classes are to be included.

These of course counts both built-in and user-defined classes. I understand that there

My thanks to @FrederickCheung for clarifying this.

**Comments**

Determining numbers of comment lines requires clarification and is a different type of question than the foregoing. For these reasons I suggest it be made a separate question (clarified appropriately). Note that a comment may be on a line by itself, at the end of a line preceded by code or between `begin=` and `end=`. Moreover, the character `#` does not always precede a comment (e.g., `s = "#{cat}" # assign name of cat to s`. Counting comments clearly is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Somehow it didn't occur to me that you can use introspection for _counting_ those things. For some reason I immediately assumed that the OP wants to know exact source locations too (as if he was writing a static analyzer, or something). You'll need a parser for comments, though. :)

Comment: `C.instance_variables` returns the instance variables of `C` (which is simply an empty `Array` since `C` doesn't have any instance variables). What the OP presumably wants is the instance variables of instances of `C`.

Comment: @Jörg, yes, of course. It's late. I'll fix that. (`C.instance_variables` is not necessarily empty, however: `class C; @c='cat'; end; C.instance_variables #= [:@c]`.) Can you help with `ObjectSpace`?

Comment: ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] counts singleton classes too (observe how the two change as you add a class or add a singleton method to an object)

Comment: Well, with little work we can count instance of the classes ourselves. Here is a very basic example:
`
class A;
  @@classes = [];
  def initialize;
    @@classes  << self;
  end;
  def self.classes;
    @@classes;
  end;
end;
 a=A.new; a2=A.new;
A.classes;
`

Comment: @Darek, I'm afraid that won't work. Suppose `a=A.new`. Then if we reassign `a` (e.g., `a='cat'`), the instance of `A` will be garbage-collected, at which time there will be no instances of `A`. Your suggested code, however. retains a reference to that instance and therefore prevents garbage collection, so you infer that one instance still exists.

Comment: @CarySwoveland 1. It was very basic example. I was aware that you have to manage assigning and deletion of a new instances. You can use `WeakRef` from the standard library. You still need to run garbage collector but you don't need to check every object, as `each_object` does. So it should be faster. 2. Garbage collector may not work (as fair I remember, it won't work on Jruby; it won't work on pry [version: 1.0.0.pre1; ruby: 2.0]). Ruby MRI from 1.9.3 to 2.2 have, I think, 3 different garbage collectors.